# What is the purpose of fanatec wheelbase and is it essential?

Tags: xbox-360

I am planning to buy fanatec wheel, pedals, shifter & stand for my xbox 360. What is the purpose of fanatec wheelbase(https://www.fanatec.com/us-en/wheel-bases) and is it essential to have one for the racing wheel setup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically the part that a normal steering wheel set comes with. It acts primarily as a base to attach different Fanatec steering wheels to (just the actual wheel), which are attached to the chrome shaft coming out of the base.

Other than that, it's used to provide a customizable way to make your own setup. You can choose the wheel, the pedals, the shifter, whatever fits with it.

I wouldn't say it's essential to have one for a racing setup. That depends on your preference, however. I think the high-end Fanatec range surrounding this base provides one of the most realistic and durable ways to sim racing games. There are plenty of other high-end racing sets that provide plenty of realism for a more reasonable price.

A picture to clarify what I meant:

[image]

Comment: can you post some picture so that i can be more clear ?

Comment: thanks for the picture, so u mean if i am buying this one http://www.fanatec.com/us-en/racing-wheels/forza-motorsport-csr-wheel-us.html i can use it without the wheelbase but if i want more realism then i can take the wheel from it and mount it to the wheelbase in your picture.. right ?

Comment: It doesn't look like the wheel in your picture is detachable. I think you need specific wheels made for the wheelbase.